# A var_dump equivalent for sending data with email

Tags: php, var-dump

I've been looking for a php library that allows me to send formatted data (like krumo) for variables via email.

This is because I've created an error handler that sends an email with the data on production environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the data if you want it to be machine readable.

If you want it to be human readable, you can either supply the second argument `TRUE` to [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to return the data as a string, or use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to catch the output of `var_dump()` into a string.

e.g.

```
// For machine-readable results
$dataStr = json_encode($data);
// ...or...
$dataStr = serialize($data);

// For human-readable results
ob_start();
var_dump($data);
$dataStr = ob_get_clean();
// ...or...
$dataStr = print_r($data, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks, right now i'm using var_export with the argument to buffer it instead of printing, but on the email it doesn't get the new lines formatted.

Answer (score 8):

```
mail('someone@somewhere.com', 'dump', print_r($obj, true));
```

would send human-readable versions of $obj's contents. If you need type/sizing information, you can use var_dump, but will need to use the ob functions to capture its output, as it doesn't have a 'return instead of outputting' option.

Comment: thanks, i'm gonna Try this. But I need the paragraph formatting too, because it prints everything on the same line.

Comment: That'd be your mailer viewing it as html or something. if you're on Thunderbird or similiar, there's a "view source" for emails where you'd get the raw text, which should have the linebreaks honored.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `json_encode()` and send variables as a JSON string in the email.

Answer (score 0):

another way you can send it as HTML 
For example

```
$sent = "<pre>".var_dump($data,true)."</pre>";
```

But make sure to set the headers of the email content to

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: You need to supply `true` as the second argument to get it to return the result and not just write it to the output buffer...

Comment: Thanks, I used var_export, but the output comes with no paragraph formatting. That's what I need

Comment: Change `var_dump` to `var_export` or `print_r` in your code snippet, because `$sent = "<pre>".var_dump($data,true)."</pre>";` will not produce desired result.